# How to create this template for page numbering in latex

Tags: fancyhdr

How to create in the latex this style of page numbering.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the footer using [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}

\definecolor{green_colour}{RGB}{191,201,176}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\colorbox{green_colour}{\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
% \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
\pagestyle{fancy}% Set page style to use the above setup

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The rule is set as part of the `L`eft footer, which is done first. This is followed by the `C`enter footer, which sets a `\colorbox` with the page number overtop of the `L`eft footer/rule. You can, of course, also do this using a single element within the footer, if needed.

Comment: Thank you Werner. Thank you. This line has how to color it?

Comment: @ItamarBarbosadeLima: Use `\textcolor{<colour>} {\rule[.]{.}{.}}` where you have `<colour>` defined somewhere.